# Is there any workflow to send e-mail periodically?

Tags: workflow, email, update, notifications

I need information about a sharepoint workflow

Here are the things that I want my sharepoint list to do:

1) The list will include a choice column (yes/no) I need this column to be updated periodically by each user, for example every 3 months.

2)After every lapse of time I want the users to receive an e-mail notification that says they need to update that share point column.

Is there any workflow or tool that can help me perform the activities described above?

any other way to do it?

I would appreciate your help
Thank You.

Comment: Have you tried one of the SharePoint designer core actions called "Pause for duration"?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Site Workflow if you want to just send reminders to the group irrespective of any condition on the list items.
[image]

If you have to check any condition like sending a reminder from the date the flag has updated. Then use the logic as shown above in the list workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are 2 actions that can help you implement this

1. Pause Until --> this will take DateTime as parameter
2. Pause for Duration --> This will take parameter as Days, Hours or Minutes

[image]